# C# IOptions can't implicity convert my object to the interface to inject it into my services AddSingleton

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, appsettings

I am learning how to use MongoDB with C# ASP.NET and I have been following this guide that Microsoft has on using MongoDB [Mongo Doc Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). I have gotten to step 3 of the Add a configuration model section and I am trying to inject my configuration interface in the service singleton so it resolves the instance of my configuration model like the guide says. I am using the exact same code as the guide just with my objects as its though it keeps throwing an error stating that `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Models.UserDBSettings' to 'Models.IUserDBSettings'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. So I was wondering how do I fix this? thanks for you help in advance

Here is my code:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<UserDBSettings>(
            Configuration.GetSection(nameof(UserDBSettings)));

        services.AddSingleton<IUserDBSettings>(sp =>
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UserDBSettings>>().Value); 
            // the line above throws the error and matches this line of code in the guide                                                                             services.AddSingleton<IBookstoreDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

        services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();

        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

UserDBSettings

```
    public class UserDBSettings
{
    public string UserCollectionName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DataBaseName { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserDBSettings
{
  string UserCollectionName { get; set; }
  string ConnectionString { get; set; }
  string DataBaseName { get; set; }
}
```

}

And then my app settings contains the information for connection:

```
{
 "UserDBSettings": {
  "UserCollection": "Users",
  "ConnectionString": "mongodb://connectionAdresss",
  "DatabaseName": "DBName"
 },
```

Comment: Or... Just ditch the interface. I never understand interfaces on plain old data objects. Interfaces indicate a contract, sure, but they also imply that there might exist an alternate implementation. What possible alternate implementation of a bag of properties are you really going to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DI container requires that the service class you are registering actually implement the interface.

```cs
public class UserDBSettings : IUserDBSettings
{
    public string UserCollectionName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DataBaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks I missed that. You always miss the the smallest thing and then are scratching your head for while trying to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark `UserDBSettings` as implementing `IUserDBSettings` interface (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)) otherwise it is just 2 types which happen to have the same properties:

```
public class UserDBSettings : IUserDBSettings
{
    public string UserCollectionName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DataBaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Chris said:

> The DI container requires that the service class you are registering actually implement the interface

Best practice is to work with an interface. If there is any reason you do not use an interface, you could try this:

```
services.Configure<UserDBSettings>(
    options => Configuration.GetSection("UserDBSettings").Bind(options));
```

In your class you could use it like:

```
public YourConstructor(IOptions<UserDBSettings> userDBSettings)
{
    _userDBSettings = userDBSettings.Value;
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you ;)